# Don't show listview of Arralist in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm not Able to show a list of Arraylist in a ListFragment of ViewPager ... why ? the fragment layout is load, but list not show...

Thanks in advance for any help

SettingActivity.java

```
public class SettingActivity extends FragmentActivity {

List<Fragment> fragments;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,TemiFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,ImpostazioniFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,InfoFragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
    mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);...
```

TemiFragment.java

```
public class TemiFragment extends ListFragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final LinearLayout pager = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temi,container,false);
    ListView listaTemi = (ListView) pager.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    List<TemiLista> lista = new ArrayList<TemiLista>();
    lista.add(new TemiLista(R.drawable.tema1, R.string.titolo_1, R.string.desc_1));
    lista.add(new TemiLista(R.drawable.tema1, R.string.titolo_1, R.string.desc_1));
    lista.add(new TemiLista(R.drawable.tema1, R.string.titolo_1, R.string.desc_1));

    listaTemi.setAdapter(new TemiAdapter(this.getActivity(), lista));

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temi,container,false);
}}
```

TemiAdapter.java

```
public class TemiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<TemiLista> lista;
ViewHolder holder;

public TemiAdapter(Context context, List<TemiLista> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (lista == null) ? 0 : lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temi_inflate, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.avatar = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        holder.titolo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titolo);
        holder.descrizione = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.descrizione);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    TemiLista riga = lista.get(position);
    holder.avatar.setImageResource(riga.getImage());
    holder.titolo.setText(riga.getTitolo());
    holder.descrizione.setText(riga.getDescrizione());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView avatar;
    public TextView titolo, descrizione;
}
```

}

temi_inflate.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="ciao"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descrizione"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:text="ciaociao"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreateView` return `inflated layout(pager)` instead of `inflating new layout`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final LinearLayout pager = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temi,container,false);
    ListView listaTemi = (ListView) pager.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    List<TemiLista> lista = new ArrayList<TemiLista>();
    lista.add(new TemiLista(R.drawable.tema1, R.string.titolo_1, R.string.desc_1));
    lista.add(new TemiLista(R.drawable.tema1, R.string.titolo_1, R.string.desc_1));
    lista.add(new TemiLista(R.drawable.tema1, R.string.titolo_1, R.string.desc_1));

    listaTemi.setAdapter(new TemiAdapter(this.getActivity(), lista));
    return pager;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ...you are the best :)

Comment: @user2198593 Happy to help you... :-)